# Why is Pojo2Json converter (using Jackson) looping

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

To convert generically a set of Pojos to a Json string I found several descriptions like
https://brunozambiazi.wordpress.com/2015/08/15/working-with-json-in-java/

and created the following method:

```
public static String convertObjectToJsonString(Object pojo) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String dataAsJsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(pojo);
    return dataAsJsonString;
}


and tried to test it with 

@Test
void getDataAsJson() throws Exception {
    User user = new User("5", "theName", "theEmail", "theGender", "theStatus");
    final String jsonObj = PojoToJsonConverter.convertObjectToJsonString(user);
    System.out.println( jsonObj );
}
```

But it throws a stackoverflow in line 24 which is mapper.writeValueAsString(pojo);
and I did not found a meaningful explanation.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector._findFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:58)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector.collect(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:41)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector.collectFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:36)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass._fields(AnnotatedClass.java:349)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.fields(AnnotatedClass.java:321)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addFields(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:379)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:308)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getJsonValueAccessor(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:196)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.findJsonValueAccessor(BasicBeanDescription.java:252)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.findSerializerByAnnotations(BasicSerializerFactory.java:346)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory._createSerializer2(BeanSerializerFactory.java:216)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:165)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1388)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1336)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:510)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:713)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:308)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:4110)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3413)
  at ch.automatedtesting.gorestinfra.impl.businessobjects.PojoToJsonConverter.convertObjectToJsonString(PojoToJsonConverter.java:24)


This is the Pojo for User:

  public class User  implements BusinessObject {

  public static final String USER_ID      = "id";
  public static final String USER_NAME    = "name";
  public static final String USER_EMAIL   = "email";
  public static final String USER_GENDER  = "gender";
  public static final String USER_STATUS  = "status";

  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String email;
  private String gender;
  private String status;

  public User(String id, String name, String email, String gender, String status) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.email = email;
      this.gender = gender;
      this.status = status;
  }

  public User(String id) {
      this(id, "", "", "", "");
  }


  public String getId() {
      return id;
  }

  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
      return email;
  }

  public String getGender() {
      return gender;
  }

  public String getStatus() {
      return status;
  }


}
```

Comment: Add your user class please

Comment: Thanks Darren for that excellent administration! I thought the post would be to long with the Pojo. Now I'm impressed that every detail is checked, really cool.

Comment: Whats in the `BusinessObject` interface?

Comment: it is an empty marker interface

Comment: Hei Darren, the code worked after shutting down intellij and the machine. Sorry for this and thanks a lot for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

I installed the example in my project and it ran without problem.
Then I used the Pojo2JsonConverter with the example user, it worked.
Eventually I replaced the User class posted - and it worked - with the same code as before.
the only thing I did is close intellij and shut down the machine over night.
I had this phenomena a while ago when I debugged a code without finding any error but the test always failed. After a reboot it worked.
Maybe time to get the newest version of Intellij.